# How to check if zombie processes are still listening to ports?

Tags: awk, grep, netstat

I use the following script to trace zombie processes which are running:

```
ps aux | awk '{ print $8 " " $2 }' | grep -w Z
```

I also use `nestat -tulpn | grep <regex>`, to check if a particular port is busy or not.

I'm trying to pass the output of the first query to the second, to check if the zombie processes are listening to any port? Is it possible?

Comment: I thought when a process became a "zombie" everything allocated to it was released. I thought a zombie was just an entry in the process table waiting to be reaped...

Comment: You could try using `lsof` to see any processes with open (IPv4) sockets: `lsof -i 4 -a`.

Comment: I think Wu has cited the situation where a connection is in a wait-closing state which exactly what's happening. I want to clear all instances of a running script and release all resources the instance is using, for a clean restart.

Answer (score 4):

As commented by Brad Allred, zombie process doesn't hold any system resource. It can't listen to ports, hold file descriptors or userspace memory. There is only minimal amount of information in the kernel, such as the return status.

However, there is a catch for TCP, which has nothing to do with zombie proc. If a connection is in the wait-closing state, which could take a couple of minutes, new socket can't listen on the same port. This can happen even if the process holding the former socket has dead.

Comment: I think you have hit the nail here. I want to find out if a dead process is keeping a tcp port busy? If yes, how will I release that port since the process listening to it is already dead?

Comment: It's better for you to show the relevant ps/nestat entries. Do you see any FIN_WAIT1 conection?